# Getting a null error in Jest test

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

i am new to LWC and jest test.So while doing the testing i have got an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

js file

```
@wire(getItemProperty, { iId: '$contactId' })
    GetItemProperty({data}){
        if (data) {
            this.itemValue= data.itemValue;
            this.itemValueColor=data.itemValueColor;
           
           this.template.querySelector('div.itemValueColor').style.setProperty('--itemColor', data.itemValueColor)
```

}

How to fix this?can someone help?

Comment: Are you able to share the relevant part of the component & the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your test. In your component's code, you have this selector:

```js
this.template.querySelector('div. itemValueColor').style.setProperty('--itemColor', data. itemValueColor)
```

But there is no element in your markup that matches the `div. itemValueColor`  selector. This explains your error.

As a best practice you should not apply style in this way with LWC because you're not supposed to modify the DOM manually unless your mark the element with the `lwc:dom="manual"` attribute (see [Manipulate the DOM with JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library)). This only useful in specific cases.
In your case, you'll want to write a getter for the style:

```html
<div style={myDynamicStyle}>...</div>
```

```js
get myDynamicStyle() {
  return `color: ${this.itemValueColor};`;
}
```

Comment: Updated the example in my answer to use the dynamic itemColor value. I still don't get why you'd want a CSS variable for this? Note that you can't use CSS variables in Jest tests as they are not supported by JSDOM (the virtual browser environment used in tests): https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1895